# discord.js reactions TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: discord.js

So i was trying to collect reactions from an embed but im still getting this error:

```
      var peopleReacted = embedsend.reactions.get(party).users.array();
                                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at Timeout._onTimeout
```

Here's my code:

```
message.channel.send(`${boost} **GIVEAWAY** ${boost}`, embed).then(sentEmbed => {
  sentEmbed.react(party)});
      
    setTimeout(function() {

      var random = 0;
      var winners = [];
      var inList = false;

      var peopleReacted = embedsend.reactions.get(party).users.array();
```

I've also been trying using
`sentEmbed.reactions.get` or `cache.get` but then i get `sentEmbed is not definied`

Comment: btw `embedsend` is `var embedsend = embed;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the errors is in `embedsend.reactions.get(party).users.array();`, because (assuming u're in d.js version 12), you must instead use `.cache`, so make it `embedsend.reactions.cache.get(party).users.array();`

Also, `var embedsend = embed;` is not a message, it is an embed object. Instead, use `var embedsend = message.channel.send('${boost} **GIVEAWAY** ${boost}', embed);`, then it will be set to the actual message you sent, rather than the embed.